# What our the community quality standards?

Tags: soporte

I tried to ask a question, but it was rejected because, "it does not meet our quality standards".  I'm not sure how my question failed to meet those standards.  How can I improve my question?

Comment: It appears your question has been deleted.  Can you tell us what it was about?  As a starting point, refer to our [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I've asked questions in other forums before, and never had them flagged.  I've always followed my intuition about what is a well formed question.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me exactly the same thing and it appears that there is an algorithm that checks the length of the text of the question, if it is too short then that message appears. What I have to do was to rephrase in order to make it a little bit longer and skip that validation.

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered in the official FAQ for the StackExchange system, [meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq):
[What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

> **What can I do to get the system to accept my question?**
>
> Make sure your question has
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable explanation of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual sentences
>
> If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit on our network.

Read the full answer to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to get past the screening algorithm by doing two things:  making the question a little longer, and asking it in English instead of Spanish.

I expect the screening algorithm to be altered in the Spanish language and culture forum to allow for questions asked in Spanish, even if the Spanish is not quite correct.

In general, if I criticize my own style, it's that I'm too verbose.  I find it strange that the algorithm would penalize me for being terse.

Comment: But that's out of our control, you should forward that to Meta.SO.

Comment: @JS.  Point taken.  But I'd rather see the point debated here, before one of us takes it to Meta SO.  It's possible that the consensus here is that the quality standards are doing what they ought to do.